# How do I work equations of motion into pymunk and draw them in pymunk?

Tags: python, physics, pyglet, chipmunk, pymunk

Running equations of motion within `pymunk` is pretty easy, but once I have to draw it in a window I get a little confused. How would you set up a simple equation of motion (force linearly depends on `x position`, for example) within the `@window.event` section of the program that runs the equations of motion while updating the window with the positions and shapes of the bodies?

Comment: Can you post anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935271/how-do-i-assign-values-to-a-variable-with-a-schedule-function-in-pyglet 

Here's an example of a very related question I've asked with a simple example

Comment: Consider also adding the `python` tag to that question to get more views. The ones you added have relatively little activity.

Comment: The question, as it is written now, probably only appeals to a a very niche group of people. And your related question isn't exactly related, it's more of a typo question / missunderstanding of fundamentals. Where this sounds a bit more complicated, so getting the code you're trying to work with might help us.